# Typescript image.src then store in a variable get the previous image data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, opencv, ionic3

I'm currently developing an app with Ionic and I have to take a picture of something, then use it with OpenCV. To do that, I have to put it in a src tag and use it.
The problem is, whenever I execute my function, it takes the previous picture instead of the captured one.

This is my function to take the picture and assign it to the src tag :

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.capturedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.image = <HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById("capture");
      this.image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
     }, (err) => {
      this.displayErrorAlert(err);
     });
     this.capturedImage = document.getElementById("capture");
     return Promise.resolve('Success !');
  }
```

Then, i've assign a function in the button in my html file like this

```
<button(click)="openCamera().then(this.imageDetection(this.capturedImage,this.templateImage))"></button>
```

I've then called a function like this :

```
imageDetection(capturedImage,templateImage){
    let capture = cv.imread(capturedImage);
    let template = cv.imread(templateImage);
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I will not put a function with promise in the template. The word 'this' will not work.

In template

```
  <button(click)="doSomething()"></button>
```

In component

```
  doSomething() {
     // your code here
     ....
     //then set the src
     let capture = document.getElementById('capture');
     capture.setAttribute('src', your_url_here);
  }
```

Hope this will help!